# How to keep a cup of Coffee hot enough not to burn me?

Tags: temperature

When I warm a cup of water up in a microwave I get the feeling that is gets too hot for me to drink it without burning my lips. But, then it chills too fast, which renders me to drink it all before it's cold again.

Does someone know a trick for avoiding that? Is using fire the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a thermos? There are thermally isolated cups. Also, there are many different types of them.

This one, for example, really looks like a miniaturized thermos.

[image: thermos-coffee-cup]

This one is a two-fold stainless-steel cup. Maybe better for camping. The trapped air in between two layers keep your coffee warm for a longer period.

[image: stainless-steel-camping-coffee-cup]

You can also find prettier looking two-fold glass cups. Esthetic ally, they look better.

[image: two-fold-isolating-glass-coffee-cup]

Comment: I have all of the above and will try them. The first one I don't like very much, very difficult to clean the mouth of that cup.

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords I prefer either porcelain cups (as it does not get cold in my drink span) or the one at the bottom when I require to keep my coffee hot. Some of them have a cap, which add extra isolation.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this product called 'coffee joulies'.  It's a small 'bean' shaped 'metal thing' (for lack of a better term).  the 'bean' contains a phase change material.  You place it in your cup when putting the hot coffee in - and it stores up that 'extra' heat (that which makes your cup too hot to drink right away).  The phase material will keep the cup warmer then if you just had a plain cup alone.  A bit of an expensive high tech solution, but prefered to drinking from a travel mug.

Comment: Do they work in your experience? Online reviews are, um, mixed st best?